# Is the similarity between tanh and normal distribution just coincidence?

Tags: taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, hyperbolic-functions

So, explaining to someone why tanh is used in machine learning (i.e. it squashes an open range to -1..+1, and changes most rapidly around 0), I brought up $\frac d{dx}$ $tanh(x)$, and it looks just like the normal distribution. But overlaying $e^{-x^2}$ we could see it was different, peaking at (roughly?) $\pi/2$

So we found up the Taylor series for each of them, wondering what the difference is. We discovered that the one for tanh is a bit complex looking, but that the $x^2$ term matches, the $x^4$ term is 2/3 vs. 1/2, and then the $x^6$ term diverges more.

I hope this question is not too vague... but is there anything else to learn here? Or is it just coincidence that these two things used a lot in machine learning approximate each other rather well, and we should move on?

(The "someone" is currently preparing for university entrance interviews and exams, to study maths.)

The desmos graph we were playing with: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/celmmwuwte

Comment: Any increasing odd function with finite limits at $\pm\infty$ is likely to have a derivative that looks vaguely like a bell curve. (Or at worst, a sum of bell curves.) All of these functions qualify: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples

Comment: You could also use the normal cumulative distribution function to squash things between zero and one. Whether the final result is more uniformly distributed depends on whether the data is more close to normally distributed or $sech^2$ distributed (fatter tails).

Comment: @Rahul I think that would make a good answer? I.e. that they are types of sigmoid curve, and that there are others in the family, is the most useful thing to be learned here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes... the similarity is just a coincidence, but these two functions are used because they have similar properties.